# Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+5}5\binom{n-k+3}3=\binom{n+9}9$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have been given an identity to prove in two ways (using generating functions and using a combinatorial explanation that fits both sides of the equation).
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+5}5\binom{n-k+3}3=\binom{n+9}9$$
Solving it with generating functions seemed OK, noticing that both sides are generated by
$$f(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^{10}}$$
A combinatorial suggestion will be very appreciated if possible.

Comment: The statement as written is false: for $n=1$ it says that $\binom65\binom43+\binom65\binom33$, which is $30$, is equal to $\binom{10}9$, which is $10$. Is $\binom{n+5}5$ supposed to be $\binom{k+5}5$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that the lefthand side is supposed to be

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+5}5\binom{n-k+3}3\;.$$

It’s somewhat helpful to let $\ell=k+5$, so that $k=\ell-5$ and rewrite this as

$$\sum_{\ell=5}^{n+5}\binom{\ell}5\binom{n+8-\ell}3\;.$$

HINT: The righthand side is clearly the number of $9$-element subsets of the set $\{0,1,\ldots,n+8\}$. Classify these sets by their sixth smallest element. For a given $\ell$, how many $9$-element subsets of $\{0,1,\ldots,n+8\}$ have $\ell$ as sixth smallest element? Note that this means that the set must have $5$ elements smaller than $\ell$ and $3$ elements larger than $k$. Note also that because I started the set at $0$, it has $\ell$ elements smaller than $\ell$.

Comment: thank you! well explained :D

Comment: @Tom: You’re welcome!